# Using .loc to populate an empty dataframe... error = 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported'

Tags: pandas, dataframe

empty DF: [raw_count_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5kox.jpg)
htp_raw: [htp_raw - these are the values i want to enter into the corresponding columns in raw_count_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftz7z.jpg)

How could I rewrite this code...

`raw_count_df` is the empty DF with the column headers `htf_one, htf_two, htf_three and htf_average` (the columns I am populating)

htf_raw is a dataframe containing the values I want to enter into the empty dataframe.

Using loc this code would identify the column `htf_one` and then use the index of the empty dataframe to place the value into the correct place. I only want values from `htf_raw` which match the index of the empty dataframe.

This code worked recently...

```
raw_count_df['htp_one'] = htp_raw.loc[raw_count_df.index, 'htf_one']
raw_count_df['htp_two'] = htp_raw.loc[raw_count_df.index, 'htf_two']
raw_count_df['htp_three'] = htp_raw.loc[raw_count_df.index, 'htf_three']
raw_count_df['htp_average'] = htp_raw.loc[raw_count_df.index, 'average']
```

Now I am getting this error..

> Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

I am not sure how I would re-write this code using .reindex etc to populate the dataframe in the same way.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the two dataframes in addition to the desired outcome?

Comment: I have added a snapshot of the target df and the df with the values i want

Comment: `df.set_index('column_name')`?

Comment: Sadly not, I want to use the index of raw_count_df to select the values to use from htp_one etc.